# Extract WAV from an MP4, process and then remux it back

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a large number of x264+AAC MP4 files. I have written an audio filter that operates on PCM wav files that I want to apply to the audio on all my videos, replacing the existing audio with the filtered version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually accomplished this with a DOS batch file and FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -i "%~f1" "%~f1.wav"

audiofilter "%~f1.wav"

ffmpeg -i "%~f1" -i "%~f1.wav" -vcodec copy -acodec libvo_aacenc "%~f1.complete.mp4"

move /Y "%~f1.complete.mp4" "%~f1"
```

Comment: ffmpeg has audio filtering capabilities. You could possibly do this in one ffmpeg command depending on what `audiofilter` does.

Comment: That's true. In this case though, the filter is very specialized.